# what's wrong with this server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to test a simple socket.io websocket server. The tool I found for testing socket.io in the command line was iocat.

The server:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(12345);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('test', function(msg){
    console.log('test msg: ' + msg);
    io.emit('test', 'Test answer');
  });
});
```

I started it with `node socket.js` command and disabled any web servers running on this machine.

This worked. The server responded ok to the connect and disconnect event but not for the 'test' message:

```
me@whatever:~/prj/client$ iocat --socketio ws://localhost:12345 
> test
> asdfasdf
>
```

server response:

```
me@whatever:~/prj/client$ node socket.js 
a user connected
user disconnected
a user connected
user disconnected
```

Any knows why ? I would prefer a command line tester, because I want to put my web server on https, Apache proxy and sub urls. So I want to make sure I baby-step on it and nothing else is interfering.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the server.  As my modified answer below explains, your client is sending a message name of `message`, not `test` so your server never sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a socket.io server, but you are trying to use a webSocket command line utility to communicate with it.

A socket.io server does use a webSocket under the covers as the base level transport, but adds an additional layer on top of the webSocket and thus requires a socket.io client to complete the connection and exchange data with a socket.io server.

So:

```
socket.io server <==> socket.io client
webSocket server <==> webSocket client
```

So, you need a socket.io client to communicate with your socket.io server or you can dumb your server down to just a webSocket server using any one of several webSocket modules available for nodejs.

---

New part of the answer, now that the question has morphed into a question about how to use `iocat` properly.

A socket.io message has two parts to it, the message name and the message data.  With your use of `iocat`, you are sending data only (with a default message name of `message`).  It appears you need to use the `-e` option to set the message name to 'test' that you want to send.  Or change your server to listen to the default message name of `message` that iocat uses.  It is a bit odd that iocat doesn't let you directly specify the message name AND the message data on each transmission.

Comment: As you were answering I was editing the question. I used iocat now, that supports socket.io, but didn't work also.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira - I don't know anything about `iocat` - I use real socket.io clients written by the library authors and don't have any difficulties like this.  I do know that using a regular socket.io library, the connect URL has various query parameters on it that are part of the initial connection establishment. Is there any reason you don't just write yourself a 10 line socket.io client using the actual socket.io client library?  You can create one for either the browser or for a node.js app.  That's what I do when I want to test things.  Then, you're not debugging/having iocat.

Comment: The reason why I want a command line test is because I want to use it behind an Apache proxy, sub urls and https and want to test various configurations in the command line so I can go baby-steping on it. :)

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira - Well, your question is not really about socket.io.  It's about how to properly use iocat then.  There's nothing wrong with your server (per the title of your question).  The question is how do you properly use iocat to do what you want.  That I can't help you with.  I answered the question as it was when I submitted my answer.  You've taken the question in a direction now that I can't help with.  You will have to either debug it yourself or find someone who knows iocat.